# Need to remove whitespace below the images

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image-processing

I need to remove the whitespace below the images, as shown here: http://www.sugarkandy.com/category/electronics/

I am using Wordpress and have toiled a lot with the styles.css but no success.
Have played with various image sizes, types etc- but can;t remove this white space.
The images are using tiles and the css code for the tiles section is:

```
    /* Homepage Tiles
    ----------------------------------------------- */

    /**
    * Grid container
    */
   #tiles {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative; /** Needed to ensure items are laid out relative to this         container **/
    margin: 0;
          }

/**
 * Grid items
 */
   #tiles li {
    width: 220px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: none; /** Hide items initially to avoid a flicker effect **/
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 4px;
             }

   #tiles li img {
    display: block;
                 }
```

I am not very hands on HTML and have spent a lot of time trying to find a solution but no success.

Also, currently the colorbox pop up opens on clicking on the title of the image- is it possible to open the pop up by clicking anywhere on the image? Like it is with the Theme section of Wordpress ( while changing, activating or deactivating a theme).

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Saurabh

Comment: Belongs on: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You need to find a way to stop this being added `<p class="link-btn"></p>`inside your anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you seem to have an empty p tag inside of your div containers which has a class of “view view-first”. And then you have a class of .view p in your style.css which has a padding: 10px 20px 20px;. This is why you have the whitespace. Remove the empty p tag and get rid of the class of .view p if it’s not needed elsewhere.

Add display: block; and height: 100%; to the a tag under class mask to make the whole image selectable when you hover and click on it.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Do you have any clue about the second part of my issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove this part of code :

```
<p class="link-btn"></p>
```

You don't seem to need it.

For the second part of you problem, if you want the color box to pop up when clicking on the entire image you have to apply the same behavior on your image as on the image title. I don't know how it's done on your side. In HTML it would be :

```
<a href="your_link"><img src="your image" /></a>
```

In jQuery it would give you something like that :

```
$('.myclass').onClick(function() {
// code to display the pop up
});
```

where `myClass` is a class that you have to applied to both your image and your image title.

Comment: Hi Olivier, It worked like a charm. Thanks. Do you have any idea about the second part of my issue? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @SaurabhJindal, I updated my answer so I can explain to you how to deal with your second problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the html code `<p class="link-btn"></p>` off of each product and that should work, if it is within wordpress you could reference the class and use `{display:none;}` to hide it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. Do you have any clue about the second part of my issue? Thanks a lot:)

Comment: one solution i can think of is you could make the whole div a `link`and that could work you can see how to do that with my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/algib/kTm56/1/)